# How to emulate network failures (chaos testing) on clusters with cilium

Tags: ebpf, cilium

Could you please provide me the information about the available tools for emulating network failures on Cilium/eBPF-based Service Mesh solutions?
Previously I used Chaos Mesh https://chaos-mesh.org/ but emulating network-related issues (packet delay or loss) doesn't work.
I suppose Chaos Mesh simulates network issues by manipulating with /etc/hosts, while Cilium bypasses it.

I tested https://github.com/cilium/chaos-testing-examples but it seems no longer maintained or supported, thus not working.

Any help appreciated!
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any Chaos Testing tool that was specifically built to work with the eBPF-based datapath of Cilium.

Depending on your Cilium configuration, existing tools may work. For example, if you are not bypassing large part of the network stack (ex. using Cilium's legacy host routing), any sort of chaos testing relying on iptables rules would likely work.

However, in the highest-performance settings, Cilium bypasses large parts of the network stack using eBPF. In those cases, chaos testing tooling would probably have to use eBPF as well.